# Swift inout passed array does not seem to effect original array

Tags: swift, inout

I have a simple case where I must not be using inout correctly.

```
import Foundation

func test_inout(file_data: inout Array<String>){

          let inString = "abc,def,xyz"
            let file_data = inString.split { $0 == ","}.map(String.init)
            print(file_data)
        }

var array: Array = ["initial string"]
test_inout(file_data: &array)
print(array)
```

The output is:

```
["abc", "def", "xyz"]
["initial string"]
```

The contents of the passed array has changed as seen by the first print but has not changed as seem by the second print. I do have it as a var and used the & in the call.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You are not even using the original array elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `inout` just fine. The problem is the way you use `let`. You are creating *another* `file_data` that overshadows the `inout` variable; the `inout` itself is never touched, so nothing happens to it.

Solution: In this line:

```
let file_data = inString.split { $0 == ","}.map(String.init)
```

...delete `let`.